# Finding common elements of a list based on some criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The input is in form of a list of tuples,

```
left_corners = [((380, 456), 1), ((1129, 456), 2), ((354, 328), 3), ((1137, 325), 4)]
right_corners = [((784, 456), 1), ((1535, 456), 2), ((778, 328), 3)]
```

The common elements would be the ones which have the second element of the tuple as `1, 2, 3` so I would want the final representation to look like -

```
[(((380, 456), 1),((784, 456), 1)), (((1129, 456), 2),((1535, 456), 2)), (((354, 328), 3), ((778, 328), 3))]
```

I can't think of a solution without a few loops (looping over both the elements and appending the elements which have the same second element in a common list). Is there a more pythonic way? I am open to other representations of this in numpy or something too.

**Assumptions:** 
We can assume both lists are sorted with the key being the second element of the list, but either `left_corners` or `right_corners` might have more elements than the other

Comment: In this example, if you just loop over the two lists together e.g. with `zip`, you would get pairs with the same second element. Is this always the case, or do you want to show an example that does not depend on this? And do you care about the ordering in the output?

Comment: `list(map(tuple, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(sorted(left_corners + right_corners, key=itemgetter(1)), itemgetter(1)))))`. Does it look more pythonic? :D *[`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)*

Comment: @OlvinRoght This would include the unmatched `((1137, 325), 4)` at the end. The question is unclear about whether that is required or not.

Comment: Can we assume the "common" elements are sorted? Or are they random?

Comment: @alaniwi, it's not the main problem of this code sample :D

Comment: I have re-edited my post with some assumptions. Thanks for al your answers, I will check it!

Comment: @PyWalker2797 Please can you show the _whole_ output (without using `...`) in order to show whether the `((1137, 325), 4)` should be included somehow or omitted.

Comment: Because it is half seeming that all you need is `[t for t in zip(left_corners, right_corners)]` -- or there might be more to it.

Comment: it is not clear what the output is supposed to be, please state clearly how the output is defined

Comment: Updated the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use dictionaries, you could do something a bit more efficient

```
group_lists = {}
for corner in (left_corners+right_corners):
  group_lists[corner[1]] = group_lists.get(corner[1], [])
  group_lists[corner[1]].append(corner)

output = [group_lists[k] for k in group_lists]
```

And if you want your output to be a list of tuples instead of a list of lists you would just have to change that last line to

```
output = [tuple(group_lists[k]) for k in group_lists]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first, second = (left_corners, right_corners) if len(left_corners) > len(right_corners) else (right_corners, left_corners)

[(i, j) for i in first for j in second  if i[1] == j[1]]
```

I assumed that the second element (key to unify the tuples) can be anything not just `1, 2, 3`

Another assumption is that the second element is sorted but can skip numbers for example, if this is not the case, then `zip` is the way to go.

```
left_corners = [(X, 1), (Y, 2), (Z, 3)]
right_corners = [(A, 1), (B, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (not sure, as the problem is not very clearly stated) this is what you want:

```
good_corners = [ [ t for t in corners if t[1] in {1,2,3}] for corners in (left_corners, right_corners) ]
result = list(zip(*good_corners))
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght as the OP clarified, sorting is not needed at all - the lists are already sorted; so I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: This might break on this case.. `right_corners = [((784, 456), 1), ((778, 328), 3)]`

Answer (score 0):

How about a list comprehension?

```
a = [k for k in left_corners if k[1] in [1,2,3]] + [k for k in right_corners if k[1] in [1,2,3]]
```

output:

```
[((380, 456), 1), ((1129, 456), 2), ((354, 328), 3), ((784, 456), 1), ((1535, 456), 2), ((778, 328), 3)]
```

This is only valid, if the ordering is irrelevant. If it needs to have the order you can sort using a lambda function:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

output:

```
[((380, 456), 1), ((784, 456), 1), ((1129, 456), 2), ((1535, 456), 2), ((354, 328), 3), ((778, 328), 3)]
```

Comment: Have you tested it? (Gives me an empty list.)

Comment: @JoKing it's still not giving me anything like the output shown in the question for the example inputs

Comment: the sorted version is the exact output

Answer (score 0):

This worked pretty well for me

```py
combined_list = list(zip(left_corners, right_corners))
```